# Using JQuery autocomplete widget with django

Tags: jquery, django, autocomplete

I realize there are a lot of posts regarding this issue, but nothing has helped me so far.

I am putting together a Django website, and i need a form with a searchable field, that is, a standard text input, that uses the given text to filter a drop-down list of options.

This feature is exactly like what is presented at the JQuery website: http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/

I just cannot seem to make it work. Below is my code:

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.pack.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        var availableTags = [

            { label: "Mosek ApS, Ruben Nielsen", value: "8" }

        ];
        $( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
            source: availableTags
         });
   });
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <input id="tags">
</body>
```

to my eye, this is completely like the example code at the JQuery site referenced above. The input box shows, but no drop-down menu appears, when i start typing the text of the label (label: "Mosek ApS, Ruben Nielsen")...

Any help..?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to include [`jQuery UI`](http://jqueryui.com/) (which is a separate library to plain jQuery) javascript and CSS:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.21/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.22/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

jQuery Autocomplete is part of jQuery UI library, so you need to include it with the page as well as the core jQuery library.